# Javascript property key - function

Tags: javascript

In the following example:

```
var tester = Object.create(null);

tester.forename = "Bob";
tester[function () { return "surname"; }] = "Jones";
```

Is javascript simply converting the function definition to a string to use as the property key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is javascript simply converting the function definition to a string to use as the property key?

Yes. Note that the string will *not* be `"surname"`. In fact, to date, it's not specified *what* the string will be, and it varies from engine to engine. On some engines, it will be roughly what you have in the source. But it would be perfectly valid (e.g., within the spec) for it to be `"dunno, some function"`. The next spec, ES6, is likely to say that, for `Function#toString`:

> An implementation-dependent String source code representation of the this object is returned. This
>   representation has the syntax of a *FunctionDeclaration* *FunctionExpression*, *GeneratorDeclaration*,
>   *GeneratorExpession*, *ClassDeclaration*, *ClassExpression*, *ArrowFunction*, *MethodDefinition*, or *GeneratorMethod*
>   depending upon the actual characteristics of the object. In particular that the use and placement of white space, line
>   terminators, and semicolons within the representation String is implementation-dependent.

*(This is the January 2014 wording.)*

But that's the next spec, which isn't final yet, and will probably change a bit as the spec approaches completion (particularly with regard to native functions). As of the current spec, `Function#toString` can return anything it likes, and it need not vary from function to function.

Comment: Must i assign to a variable first in order to use the result of an expression as a property key

Comment: @MartyWallace: You *are* using the result of an expression as a property key; currently, your code has a function expression, which results in a function instance, which is then implicitly coerced to a string. If your goal is to *call* the function, then you need a call expression. Here's a call expression calling a function defined by a function expression and using it as a property name (note the `()` after the last `}`): `tester[function () { return "surname"; }()] = "Jones";` That would set `tester.surname` to `"Jones"`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The property names of objects are always strings.

If you attempt to use a different type, it will be coerced into string.

If you want them to be other types, you can use ES6 [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).